# How can I transfer data from AWS RDS PostgreSQL db instance to mysql db which is on a different server?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-rds, data-transfer

Till now I have been transferring the data manually by just exporting the data and then importing it to MySQL DB but now I have to automate the whole process.

I want to generate CSV and FTP these CSV files to MySQL server.

pgAdmin let me download the file through windows but when export via the "COPY" command; however, I get the error that I need to be a superuser and that I should use "\copy" instead.

And I cannot access the Operating system for the Postgre server.